# DB Project/Solution Best Practice

Tags: visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions, database-project

I have an app (ASP.NET 3.5/ VS 2010) that works with a database project.

Is there any downside to having the database project as one more project within the app solution?

Is it better to have another solution just for the database project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No real downside in the scope of this single app. If the same DB is used by multiple apps, you might be more easily able to reuse it by having it in its own solution, but even then, you could set it up as an external in your source control and be able to reference the latest build from a "lib" directory downloaded when you update source on other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

My rule of thumb is: if one project directly references another project, they should be in the same app solution.  If the projects are related, but don't reference one another, they should be their own solutions, in separate subfolders of the same main folder.  If two multi-project solutions are related, place them in separate places, then use `Add Existing Project` to reference the appropriate other project in the solution.

Most of my projects end up being solutions because I add a testing project.  So I split up every component into a separate solution, and then reference the appropriate projects in other solutions as needed using `Add Existing Project`, so I can debug from one solution into another.  But they are all kept separate and are stand-alone.

Comment: Yuck. What happens if you need a full build of the entire piece of software, consisting of 10 projects in 10 different solutions? Or do you house all lines of code in one project (which can have its own problems with code organization/visibility)?

Comment: Yes, a single project in each solution houses the main code.  All other projects are supporting projects (like test clients, experimenting projects, etc). I'd rather have good separation of code and maintenance, then worry about the number of projects and solutions.  My current project consists of 10 solutions, and the main project references projects in about 8 of the other solutions.  Works good for me, but that's my opinion.

Comment: As you mention, it's about code re-use as well.  Many of the projects are used in multiple applications.  For instance, three projects are referenced from an Access application via a wrapper.  I don't want the entire code-base together every time I need to modify the wrapper or build for the Access application.

Comment: Fair enough. I know how painful moving source control repositories to properly reflect splitting projects out for reuse can be. For my part, I prefer the ability to develop in one instance of VS, so I can hit "build" once and get working software, and also make maximum use of ReSharper's refactoring tools (which can only update code actually included in the solution).